# Error causes halt

Tags: error

Received this error
I tried to cut and paste the error but the error would disappear before I could copy or snip it

*Report error
Traceback (most recent call list)
   File “C:\blender\blender2.80\2.80\scrips\bl_operators\wm.py”,line525    …
   File “C:\blender\blender2.80\2.80\scrips\bl_operators\wm.py”,line85  …
   File “,line1,  …
   Location :-1
Note: … = more lines follow*

This error halted the program to stop
I tried to repair 
I completely uninstalled blender and reinstalled

The error followed to the freshly installed copy

Windows 10 blender 2.80

Comment: Please add the full error message from the console, otherwise we cannot provide any help.

Comment: I wish there was an easier way but I will do it

Comment: Here is the full error message        Report error
Traceback (most recent call list)
File “C:\blender\blender2.80\2.80\scrips\bl_operators\wm.py”,line525,in execute value =                 context_path_validate(context, data_path)   
File “C:\blender\blender2.80\2.80\scrips\bl_operators\wm.py”,line85,in execute value =                 context_path_validate.%s” % data_path(context, data_path) if data_path else Ellipsis    
    File “<string>,line1,<module>  
 AttributeError: SpaceError’  
   Location <unknown location>:-1